# Creating an unlimited forum hierarchy in Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates

I'm trying to design models for a forum I wish to create in Django.

So far I have:

> ```
> class Forum(models.Model):
>     name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
>     slug = models.SlugField(max_length=150)
>     description = models.TextField()
>
>     def __unicode__(self):
>         return self.name
>
> class SubForum(models.Model):
>     parent_forum = models.ForeignKey('Forum', related_name='forums')
>     parent = models.ForeignKey('self', blank=True, null=True, related_name='children')
>     name = models.CharField(max_length=300)
>     slug = models.SlugField(max_length=150)
>     description = models.TextField()
>
>     def __unicode__(self):
>         if self.parent:
>             return u'%s: %s - %s' % (self.parent_forum.name,
>                                      self.parent.name,
>                                      self.name)
>         return u'%s: %s' % (self.parent_forum.name, self.name)
> ```

This works for the most part as I am able to choose a parent category although I am not sure how to select parent of a child's parent. For example if I had the following:

```
Grandparent -> Parent -> Child
```

How would I select Grandparent from Child?

This kind of hierarchy also makes the Django admin rather messy as it doesn't cascade in an orderly fashion. Do I have to build the entire admin from scratch in order to organise this into a usable interface?

Lastly the `__unicode__` function in the SubForum model allows me to print the parent but what about a grandparent. Can I get `__unicode__` to print all ancestors?

Thanks.

Comment: Why have `SubForum`?  Why not just put the `parent` field in `Forum`?  You can still easily get a list of all top-level forums with `Forum.objects.filter(parent=None)`.

Comment: But if I had a field in `Forum` called `SubForum` with a `parent` field, could I select all a `Forum`s children knowing the name of the top level? Or would I fetch all `Forum` and `SubForum` entries and then arrange them after the query?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Using parent/child relationship

While it is true that you could use two models with *parent/child relationship* to represent you forum hierarchy, due to the fact that the models are stored in relational SQL database you have to think first how you are going to use those models so you can in turn properly model them.

If you will only every need to do [breadth-first search (BFS)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search), that is select *only immediate parents or children* of a single forum, code like you wrote it and Django ORM will be great.

You could even get the grandparent of the child but it will require a lot of SQL `SELECT` and `JOIN` operations once the ORM hits the database, which could potentially be rather slow.

### Using a single model

So while your model is ok, it's not really suitable for your requirements, or more specifically selecting `nodes` far up/down the hierarchy starting with the random node (grandparents of a child).

What you want to do is to build a simple N-ary tree data structure, or in other words, a hierarchy and [traverse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal) it. You don't really need two models for this, only one models with relationship to itself would suffice (I've called it `Node` for example). To get a N-th parent in this model you would simply loop n times each time following your relationship (this is basically a [linked-list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list))

```
n = 2 # Grandparent
node = Model.objects.get(pk=1)
while n: 
   if node.parent:
      node = node.parent
# At the end of the loop `node` points to the grandparent
```

### Modeling tree structure in SQL database

There are potentially number of ways to implement trees in a SQL database but in your case I would  suggest using [MPTT](http://articles.sitepoint.com/article/hierarchical-data-database/2), over lets say [adjacency list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjacency_list) model to build it. Both are techniques for easy manipulation and storage of such structures. [MPTT](http://articles.sitepoint.com/article/hierarchical-data-database/2) will require more writes to the database in order to add/move nodes around the tree but to select partial tree with random root (child) is super easy since you only need to filter on two integer fields.

With [adjacency lists](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjacency_list) you could potentially update the tree with fewer writes, but you would need to do much more operations to select partial tree starting from random root.

As for implementation of MPTT as a Django application try [django-mptt](https://github.com/django-mptt/django-mptt/).

Misc: nice article [hierarchical data database](http://articles.sitepoint.com/print/hierarchical-data-database) design.

Comment: I read that article whilst doing research on a tagging system.

I was hoping that I wouldn't have to deviate from the django.core too much.

Thanks for your answer, it's worth considering but I don't see the pitfalls of adjacency lists being a large problem. There wouldn't be more than 100 forums in any case and those taxing JOIN queries could be kept in a cache.

Don't you think?

Comment: @Anarchist Well, it's just that MPTT is easier to select and adjacency is easier to update and my guess is your gonna do more selects and less updates, thus the recommendation of MPTT, but both will suite you just fine and i doubt you should have any speed related issues on such small dataset.

Answer (score 0):

I would simply create one Forum model that can either have another Forum as it's parent, or have a null parent. Then if you want to print out all parents you could use a while loop like this pseudocode:

```
heirarchy = ""
f = this forum model
while f.parent is not null:
   heirarchy.append(f.parent.name)
   f = f.parent
```

to answer the other part of your question, in order to select a child while knowing the parent id, you would query Django's object structure like so:

```
Forum.objects.filter(parent=PARENT_ID)
```

and to get the grandparent of a child you would do:

```
forum_object.parent.parent
```