# How to create category tree in Django from scratch?

Tags: python, django

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Creating an unlimited forum hierarchy in Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3241751/creating-an-unlimited-forum-hierarchy-in-django)

I have model: name, slug, parent.

I want to create categories and subcategories in my project.

How to create category tree in Django from scratch?
I do not want to use packaged applications.

Comment: Please give more precisions. Why wouldn't you use existing applications. And what do you want to achieve?

Comment: I want to learn. I have model: name, slug, parent. I want to create categories and subcategories in my project

Answer (score 1):

Really not sure what you're going for; from a model standpoint, if you want to create a tree, you will want to create a recursive relationship:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey

use categories = models.ManyToManyField('self')

There are a number of existing open source projects that do what you're going for, so if you are just trying to learn and you get stuck, check out their code, and read through it.